# Copying values in Prisma write query

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm using Prisma with an postgresql database to create a soccer fantasy team application.

The schema i'm using:

```
model Team {
  ...
  selections Selection[]

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId Int
}

model Selection {
  ...
  value    Float?
  player   Player @relation(fields: [playerId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  playerId Int
  team     Team   @relation(fields: [teamId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  teamId   Int
}

model Player {
  ...
  value       Float?
  selections Selection[]
}
```

I'm getting a post request with the ID's of the selected players, like the following:

```
[78410, 71359, ..., 76341]
```

Now I want to create a new Team and a new Selection for each selected Player. Because the value of the player can change over time I want to save the value at the time of selecting that player.

I have the following query:

```
prisma.team.create({
            data: {
                userId: <userId>,
                selections: {
                    createMany: {
                         ...
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

What's the best way to put the value of the player in the selection entry (while only having the player's id)?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a nested `createMany`, the operation will automatically connect the `Selection` model to the `Team` model. If, in the process of creating a new `Selection` (through `createMany`) you also want to set the `userId` of the new `Selection`, you can just specify that property.

```js
prisma.team.create({
  data: {
    userId: <userId>,
    selections: {
      createMany: {
        data: [
          {
            playerId: <playerId>
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-single-record-and-multiple-related-records